# Drag and drop Image in appropriate position

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for windows phone 8 and want to drag and drop an image into specified position. If the position is wrong then I want to set it back to its initial position.

I am using this code to achieve this functionality.

```
void img1_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        FrameworkElement Elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        double top = Elem.Margin.Top;
        double left = Elem.Margin.Left;

      if (top>249+110/ 2 && left > 212+212/ 2)
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Top{0},Left:{1}", top, left);
      }
      else
      {
          Elem.Margin = new Thickness(30, 212, 0, 0);
      }
    }

    void img1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
    {

        FrameworkElement Elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        GeneralTransform gt = ContentPanel.TransformToVisual(Elem);
        Point currentPos = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        Elem.Margin = new Thickness(args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X - currentPos.X, args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y - currentPos.Y, 0, 0);

    }
```

Is there any built-in method that can tell intersection of appropriate Rectangle?[image]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, but as per the last part about detecting Rectangle intersection, there is a built in function of `System.Drawing.Rectangle` called `Intersect()` that you can use to detect intersection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx

Comment: Thanks but these are Image not rectangle so can I use the same for Image?

Comment: You could probably put your Image *into* a Rectangle, otherwise you'd just have to do the math manually based on the current positions of the Images you need to check.

Comment: Thanks I did it with the help of Math..:)

Comment: @Ihan I think there should be an way to find intersection of Rectangles in WIndows phone also.As u told above rectangle.intersect is only for Windows 8 not for windows phone 8 I checked it and did manually but I want to know if any method.